# Stackdriver IoT devices monitoring

Tags: google-cloud-platform, iot, stackdriver

Is there any way to set up GCP Stackdriver to alert with device ID in case that any device becomes offline? Currently I have alert that tells me that "number of active devices dropped from x to y" but I'd like to know which device (ID) is down.

Answer (score 0):

This [GCP documentation](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/cloud-iot-logging) explains about Stackdriver Logging with IoT Core devices. In the Stackdriver Logging you can see device logs and filter logs to a specific device. Also you can use [Stackdriver Monitoring](https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/how-tos/monitoring) to create dashboards, such as a dashboard for the total number of active devices in a registry.